# Difficulty in LUIS extracting numbers

Tags: botframework, bots, azure-language-understanding

I have one LUIS model for booking an audio call say "BookAcall" and i have utterances as below"
I have used prebuilt entity **Number** for extracting any numerical entity from the sentence.

*Book audio call for 5 people for 2 location*

Now, from LUIS json i got two entity as numbers.

1. **5** and other is **2** but in LUIS there is no way to understand that **5** is no Of people and **2** is no of locations

Need suggestions.
Thanks

Below is the screenshot of utterance and Entity, i have used List type entity for No of users.
[image]

```
{
  "query": "book a call tomorrow for 5 people for 2 location",
  "topScoringIntent": {
    "intent": "BookACall",
    "score": 0.9560004
  },
  "intents": [
    {
      "intent": "BookACall",
      "score": 0.9560004
    },
    {
      "intent": "CryptoTrading",
      "score": 0.0283502769
    },
    {
      "intent": "None",
      "score": 0.00855541
    }
  ],
  "entities": [
    {
      "entity": "tomorrow",
      "type": "builtin.datetimeV2.date",
      "startIndex": 12,
      "endIndex": 19,
      "resolution": {
        "values": [
          {
            "timex": "2018-06-15",
            "type": "date",
            "value": "2018-06-15"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "entity": "location",
      "type": "NoOfLocation",
      "startIndex": 40,
      "endIndex": 47,
      "resolution": {
        "values": [
          "Location"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "entity": "people",
      "type": "NoOfUsers",
      "startIndex": 27,
      "endIndex": 32,
      "resolution": {
        "values": [
          "People"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "entity": "5",
      "type": "builtin.number",
      "startIndex": 25,
      "endIndex": 25,
      "resolution": {
        "value": "5"
      }
    },
    {
      "entity": "2",
      "type": "builtin.number",
      "startIndex": 38,
      "endIndex": 38,
      "resolution": {
        "value": "2"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Are people and location entities?

Comment: I have used NoOfUsers as List type of entity in LUIS as you can see on the screenshot

Comment: So location is also an entity I suppose

Comment: @AnitaGeorge yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As DFBerry suggested in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50950519/luis-consider-time-and-duration-as-number-entity), you can create a [composite entity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-tutorial-composite-entity) and make number entity and List type entity for user as child entities. And then you can extract the number of user within that composite entity from returned response.

*Create a composite entity, like below:*

[image]

*Extract number of user from that composite entity:*

[image]

Comment: Yes...Did the same. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Add a pattern that includes the numbers in the pattern

Comment: What if use enter Five instead of numerical 5?

Answer (score 0):

> Book audio call for 5 people for 2 location

Since people and location are entities. You can try to track which number corresponds to people and location by checking the [start index and end index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-get-started-cs-get-intent#understand-what-luis-returns) of the entities.

Scenarios might be:

Book audio call for 5 people for 2 location
Book audio call for 2 location for 5 people

So if you get 2 number type entity and one location type, person type check whether which number occurred first and then which entity whether people or location occurred first. In this way you can do a mapping.

Comment: Hello Anita, I have added json result returned by LUIS. I am not able to apply your solution. Can you please go through the JSON.

Comment: What programming lang are you using to parse the result so I can give a clearer answer. Could you also provide the code where you are parsing the api response